# Fourier transform of the top-hat filter

Tags: cosmology, fourier-transform, integration

In the context of a cosmology text, I have found the following function, called a spatial top-hat filter:

$$W_{TH,R}(r)=\dfrac{3\theta(R-r)}{4\pi R^3}$$

It is claimed that this leads to:

$$W_{TH,R}(k)=3\dfrac{\sin(kR)-(kR)\cos(kR)}{(kR)^3}$$

which I assume is the Fourier transform of the expression given above. I want to be able to reproduce this result, so I attempted the following:

$$W_{TH,R}(k)=\int d^3r\ e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\cdot W_{TH,R}(r)=\int d^3r\ e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}\cdot\dfrac{3\theta(R-r)}{4\pi R^3}=$$

$$=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\ r^2\sin\theta\cdot e^{-ikr\cos\theta}\cdot\dfrac{3\theta(R-r)}{4\pi R^3}=$$

$$=2\pi\dfrac{3}{4\pi R^3}\int_0^\pi d\theta\int_0^\infty dr\ r^2\theta(R-r)\sin\theta\cdot e^{-ikr\cos\theta}=$$

$$\dfrac{3}{2R^3}\int_0^\infty dr \int_0^\pi d\theta\  r^2\theta(R-r)\sin\theta\cdot e^{-ikr\cos\theta}$$

But I cannot imagine how to proceed any further. I would like to be able to change variables as $u=\cos\theta$, but the extra $\theta$ in front of the exponential makes it seem like this would not solve anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The first two equations have the same arguments. Should the latter be a function of  $k$ instead of $r$? And is $\theta$ in the first equation the same $\theta$ as in the Fourier transform? Given the symmetry of the top-hat, I would have assumed they'd be different.

Comment: Look up integral representations of Bessel functions.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thank you, you were right. I believed that both $\theta$ would be the same, but I think that the one that appears in the definition of the top-hat filter is actually the Heaviside function. So what I was trying to do makes no sense. This is what happens when physics texts don't explain their notation... :(

Comment: @WildFeather for completeness, I've added an answer that identifies this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two primary features of the [top-hat filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-hat_filter) are,

1. angular symmetry
2. constant to some radius & zero otherwise

Hence, it seems that the $\theta$ in the $W_{TH,R}(r)$ equation is *not* the angular position but the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):
$$W_{TH,R}(r)=\frac{3}{4\pi R^3}\theta(R-r)\equiv\frac{3}{4\pi R^3}\times\begin{cases}1 & R>r \\ 0 & R < r\end{cases}$$
While this is perhaps more commonly written using $H(x)$, it is also not uncommon to use $\theta(x)$ (cf. [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html), for instance).

Using this formula should allow you to more easily compute the Fourier transform.